# Не могу понять почему регулярное выражение не изменяет содержимое переменной

Tags: php, wordpress

Пишу простой блог для практики вордпресса. Подключил форматы постов и при формате поста видео необходимо, чтоб видео удалялось из контента поста и перемещалось на превью как thumbnail. Но я даже не могу адекватно убрать видео из контента.
Использую хук the_content для фильтрации контента. Так же если есть идеи как решить вопрос с thumbnail видео буду безмерно благодарен.

Код функции в functions.php

```
//Custom function
function remove_post_video( $content ) {
    if (get_post_format() === 'video') {
        return preg_replace('/<figure.*<\/figure>/', '' , $content);
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_post_video', 0);
```

Код контента

```
<figure class="wp-block-embed is-type-video is-provider-youtube wp-block-embed-youtube wp-embed-aspect-16-9 wp-has-aspect-ratio"><div class="wp-block-embed__wrapper">
https://youtu.be/F4we73GHH9k
</div></figure>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus lacinia ante vitae ante convallis, in blandit nibh commodo. Aliquam ultricies magna quis sem hendrerit mollis. Maecenas massa nisi, euismod a ultricies non, tempor sagittis tellus. Duis sit amet vestibulum nibh, sed tempor libero. Phasellus leo arcu, vehicula ut aliquam vitae, molestie quis neque. Mauris auctor in nibh a egestas. Curabitur non dignissim nibh, vel porta sem. Praesent fringilla metus eget efficitur scelerisque. Mauris id nibh sapien. Donec imperdiet commodo auctor. Vivamus volutpat felis vitae diam pharetra, at posuere nunc blandit. Cras pretium eros a sem bibendum pretium.</p>
```

Comment: Видео вставляется в пост через другой хук, embed. Он вызывается из the_content позже. А у вас приоритет 0. Увеличьте приоритет, вместо 0 поставьте PHP_INT_MAX.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, но к сожалению увеличение приоритета не помогло. Видео все еще отображается в контенте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот так должно сработать

```
preg_replace( '/<figure([\W\w]*)<\/figure>/', '', $content );
```

Comment: Обалденно, спасибо.

Comment: Вв меня в тупик поставили. Почему `.*` не работает, а `([\W\w])` должно работать?

Comment: потому что там перевод строки, а \W хавает любые символы. но впрочем  согласен и .* работает корректно если указать модификатор single line